# Delphi: load large files with SynEdit

Tags: file, delphi, text, load, synedit

"I would recommend switching to another edit control like **SynEdit**(it can load **80 mb of text** file in few miliseconds)." - [more memory for TMemo / TRichEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690908/more-memory-for-tmemo-trichedit)

Is it possible?

To load 1,5 Mb takes me 8 sec...

My previous post: [Delphi: Form becomes Frozen while assigning strings in thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728234/delphi-form-becomes-frozen-while-assigning-strings-in-thread/6728450#6728450)

I have Delphi 2010 and UniSynEdit for Delphi 2009.

Thanks!

Comment: what happened here, is this a new question or did something go wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need a faster edit control. Notepad++ loads large files like that much faster. It's based on Scintilla. I believe there are Delphi bindings for Scintilla.

Answer (score 0):

The backend of SynEdit is a TStrings descendant which loads EVERYTHING IN ONE GO if you just use

```
ASynEdit.Lines.LoadFromFile
```

You could use on demand loading (i.e. just load visible lines, perhaps with 10 lines before and after) but you have to handle it yourself.

Comment: Are you loading it from USB or something? Thats horrendously slow

Comment: From HD. Did you try? Try in regular Notepad.

Comment: hmm... maybe I'm not clear enough. I mean, DON'T use `ASynEdit.Lines.LoadFromFile` as it will load the whole file, you have to use on demand loading technique which should only load the visible parts of the file